# Angular calling .net backend server

Tags: .net, angular

I've just got into Angular and I'm trying to call a web api (.net 5) and following microservices principles at the same time.
I have used the .net angular template to help myself using their example which is clear.
However when I try to use my controller, which is listening on a different port, it doesn't really work (the controller is another web api project).

Below my service which contacts the api gateway, which calls the target controller

```
   export class BusinessService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  private url = 'http://localhost:5010/business/all'; 

  getBusinessSectors(){
    return this.http.get<BusinessSector[]>(this.url);
  }
}

export interface BusinessSector{
  id: number;
  topic: string;
  description: string;
  associates: string[];
}
```

The angular app (and .net since it's a template) is running on https:5000, however the other controller is listening on http:5002. I don't think https is the issue, and one thing I noticed, i don't have a proxy.config file like I have seen in other Angular projects generated from scratch.

Finally, the request hits the api gateway I can see it, but apparently, i don't have anything in return

In my html component,

```
<p *ngIf="!businessSectors"><em>Loading...</em></p>

<div *ngFor="let sector of businessSectors">
    <h2>{{sector.topic}}</h2>
</div>
```

And in my component.ts

```
constructor(private businessService:BusinessService) { 
    this.businessService.getBusinessSectors().subscribe(
      response => this.businessSectors = response),
      error => console.log(error);
  }
```

And loading... is my only response.

I know it must be some tiny detail I missed, I mean .. it's just calling an api from Angular, there is no complexity.

Comment: Have you tried
`http://localhost:5010/api/business/all`
Adding `api` after port.

Also in the provided example, there is an extra `)` after `this.businessSerctors = response`

Comment: What does the browsers netwrok console show?

Comment: @YousafRaza thanks for the notice, i don't know why the compiler allowed it. I fixed it. And no, it does not come from the missing api in the request : like i said, the api gateway does receive the request (and i added /api/endpoint, the api gateway noticed it didn't recognize the route)

Comment: @MikeOne ok, hmmm, it says the "xmlHttprequest at http://localhost:5010/business/all from origin http://localhost:5000 has been blocked by CORS"  
Am i compelled to AddCors in my .net startup?? I thought by creating and injecting an http client would avoid me this step? (i know the concept of CORS but not much either)  
I'm gonna try adding CORS to my startup and see what's going on.

Comment: @MoBe Yeah either you need to allowCors or you need to setup reverse proxy for api https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54228164/how-to-setup-reverse-proxy-in-angular-2

Comment: @YousafRaza yep, that was it. Setting up the proxy solved it. Thank you very much